# Get custom Product Atributes from each products at root

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I need to get values from some custom attributes from products. I'm using separate *php* file outside *Magento* folder and I'm using mostly $shippingRates to get the information I need.

I need to first load the product from SKU. I got SKU from *Order*.as follows,

```
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
$items =$orderObj->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item):
$itemSku = $item->getSku();
endforeach;
```

I need to filter the product by *SKU* to get only needed products.
But the way I did wasn't a success.

So I tried loading products separately.

I loaded product using *ProductRepository* and *Product Model*,

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
```

and

```
$getProduct = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
```

I tried to filter product loading by sku as follows,

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$skuLoopProd = $item->getSku();
$getProduct = $productRepository->get($skuLoopProd);
```

And I tried as follows to get custom attribute value,

```
$axs = $getProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('product_weight_class')->getOptions();
foreach ($axs as $keyAttr) {
echo $keyAttr->getLabel();
}
```

but in this, I got all available options for the attribute, not the attribute value applied to the product.

What was wrong with what I tried so far?

Can please someone help me to **get text value from a custom attribute of a product that I can filter with SKU?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the product ID using Product Repository and Object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// Get the Product Repository
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

// Get the Product Id using sku
$product = $productRepository->get($productSku);

// Create the product object using product ID
$product = $productRepository->getById( $product->getId());

// Call the Attributes 
$product->getData('product_weight_class');
or
$product->getAttributeText('product_weight_class');
```

Try this and update.

Comment: I use this inside foreach loop. As I mentioned in my question. **foreach($items as $item):
//I used your code here.
endforeach;**   So I need to get custom attribute to few products. **Problem** is, when I use this, I only get attribute value for one product and loop gets stopped next time It comes to above code.

Comment: @Joey - Did you debug the values ?

Comment: Yeah, it was caused by older orders. some products were updated with new skus. but in Order, they were'n updated. so there was a conflict

Comment: @Joey - You can use product id without using sku, try to get the product ID.

Comment: still the same.  **Fatal error on=> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException' with message 'Requested product doesn't exist'  => Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->getById('15') #2**

Comment: 1st get the product id then pass it to $product = $productRepository->getById( $product->getId());
function

Comment: I did. **$productIdDirect = $item->getId();   $productForAttr = $productRepository->getById($productIdDirect);
if($productForAttr){
    $getCustAttrWeight = $productForAttr->getAttributeText('product_weight_class');
    $getCustAttrManuF = $productForAttr->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
}**